# What is the minimal correction to the harmonic series such that it converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

as you all hopefully know, the series
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k}
$$
diverges. Now I know that you can add some logarithmic corrections, such that it converges:
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k\log(k)^2}
$$
(this might be wrong, i only remember this faintly). I once saw a wiki page which explained which sort of logarithmic corrections one can (and has to) make in order for the series to converge, does anyone know?
Thx!

Comment: [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html)? (or, [in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand))

Comment: I know you didn't really ask for this, but to show how almost-convergent the harmonic series is: $\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac1{k^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges for all real positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: [the Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) shows that $\sum_{n=e^{e^{e^{e^e}}}}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n) (\ln \ln n) (\ln \ln \ln n) (\ln \ln \ln \ln n)^a}$ converges only for $a > 1$

Comment: The series cannot start at $k=1$.

Comment: Subtracting $\frac{1}{n}$ from term $\frac{1}{pn}$ makes it converge to $log(p)$. This is not the kind of "logarithmic correction" you ask for, but it is a correction that makes it converge to a logarithm...
(http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa27/aa27121.pdf, page 136)

Answer (score 4):

This is a *Bertrand's series* which are series of the form
$$\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac1{k^\alpha(\log k)^\beta},$$
and they're  known to converge if and only if

- $\alpha >1$ (by the comparison test),
- or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$ (by the integral test).

Answer (score 2):

And the "Bertrand series" idea continues indefinitely: $\sum {1\over n(\log n)(\log\log n)^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges for $\epsilon>0$, and diverges for $\epsilon=0$. Similarly with as many-fold iterated log as you'd want. All from the integral test.