# Determine if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}$ converges/diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to use the theorem that:

> If $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}=A,$$ then the positive
>   series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ are both
>   either convergent or divergent.

But no matter what convergent $b_k$ I choose I always get the limit to infinity. Does the ratio test work here? I tried but no luck.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know $\ln k\leq C k^{1/4}$ for large $k$, here $C>0$ is some constant, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\ln k}{k\sqrt{k}}\leq\dfrac{k^{1/4}}{k\sqrt{k}}=\dfrac{1}{k^{5/4}},
\end{align*}
and $\displaystyle\sum_{k}\dfrac{1}{k^{5/4}}<\infty$.

Comment: So for very large $k$, $\ln(k)$ is always smaller than potenses?

Comment: What is that? I mean, smaller than any positive exponent of $k$, one can prove, $\ln k\leq C_{\alpha}k^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha>0$, here $C_{\alpha}>0$ is some constant.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you plot $\ln(k)$ and $k^{1/4}$, you can see that after about $k\approx 4.17$, it follows that $\ln{k}>k^{1/4}.$ What you have suggested for large $k$ is the reverse.

Comment: You may try $k=1000000$, I just put in the calculator and it goes through.

Comment: Ahh... okay, it seems that at around $k=5504$, the function $k^{1/4}$ wins again. However, what was the hint for you to actually choose 1/4 as the exponent when you chose it as a majorant?

Comment: Actually you may assume $k^{\alpha}$ first, then we have $\dfrac{1}{k^{3/2-\alpha}}$, and we now want to let $3/2-\alpha>1$, then all $\alpha<1/2$ will do.

Comment: So if I had $\frac{\ln{k}}{k},$ I get $$\frac{\ln{k}}{k}\leq\frac{1}{k^{1-\alpha}},$$

this means that $a<0.$ How do I interpret this?

Comment: Using integral test, $\displaystyle\int_{e}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log x}{x}dx=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log(\log x)=\infty$, so in this case, the series doesn't converge.

Comment: Isn't the primitive function to $\frac{\log{x}}{x}$ equal to $\frac{\ln^2{x}}{2}$? Also, why doesn't the above method with choosing an $\alpha$ work here?

Comment: No, the primitive is $\log(\log x)$, as you may check by differentiation. Because you can't choose any $\alpha>0$ with both $\log k\leq k^{\alpha}$ and $1-\alpha>1$. If we force $1-\alpha>1$, then $\alpha<0$ but $\log k\leq\dfrac{1}{k^{q}}$ for $q>0$ ($q=-\alpha$ in this case) fails for large $k$.

Comment: Sorry I messed up, I thought the $\log x$ was in the denominator.

Comment: Yeah I figured but that's ok. Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: Yes, the primitive is $\dfrac{(\log x)^{2}}{2}$, doing improper integral with $x\rightarrow\infty$ still blows up.

Answer (score 4):

Try with

$$b_k=\frac{1}{k^{\frac54}}$$

**NOTE**

The trick is use an exponent between 1 and $\frac32$.

Comment: You are a genious. Sad that my book never reveals tricks like this! But now if I use it I get $$\frac{k^{5/4}\ln{k}}{k^{3/2}}=\frac{k^{3/2}\cdot k^{-1/4}\ln{k}}{k^{3/2}}=\frac{\ln{k}}{k^{1/4}}.$$ How do I know that this tends to 0?

Comment: Use that, $\ln k\leq C'k^{1/100}$ if you wish, so $\ln k/k^{1/4}\leq C'1/k^{1/4-1/100}$.

Comment: @Parseval the exponent at the denominator is $\frac32$ and $\log k$ is weaker than any positive exponent, you need also that the residual exponent is greater than 1 thus you need to choose in between 1 and $\frac32$

Comment: @gimusi, but if $\ln{k}$ is weaker than any positive exponent, isn't enough just to look at it to determine that it's converging? Also, if what you say is true, why is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{k}}{k}$$ divergent?

Comment: @Parseval yes indeed the given series converges but you have to prove it in some way

Comment: @Parseval I say that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{k}}{k^a}$ converges for all a>1

Comment: @Parvesal: This series is a case of a *Bertrand's series*  $\sum\limits_n\dfrac1{k^\alpha\,\log^\beta k}$, for which all cases of convergence are known. See for instance my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632489/what-is-the-minimal-correction-to-the-harmonic-series-such-that-it-converges/1632506#1632506)

Comment: @gimusi - So If I had $\frac{\ln^2{k}}{k^2\sqrt{k}}$ I'd need to chose $b_k =$ something between 2 and 5/2? By residual exponent, you mean the exponent of the logarithm right?

Comment: it suffices an exponent between 1 and $\frac52$, you need at least 1 in order to have $b_k$ convergent and no more than $\frac52$ in order to win over $\log k$

Comment: Can you please explain where you get the 5/2 from?

Comment: @Parseval it is the exponent of $k^2\sqrt k=k^\frac52$

Comment: So always when I have something like $$\frac{\ln(k)}{k^a},$$ I should choose an a majorant $$\frac{1}{k^t},$$ where $1 > t > a$?

Comment: @Parseval let say 1<t<a