# studying the convergence of a series:

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I  would like to study the convergence of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^2}$$

I could compare the generic element $\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and say that
$$\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{\log n}{n^2}$$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges but nothing more about.

Comment: It is $-\zeta'(2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test) test with $$\frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$$

Related OP with a more general discussion [Determine if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}$ converges/diverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586107/determine-if-sum-k-1-infty-frac-lnkk-sqrtk-converges-diverges/2586110#2586110)

Comment: Not the ratio test, the comparison test.

Comment: @zhw. Yes indeed I'm referring to limit (ratio) comparison test, thanks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 2):

By [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), your series converges if and only if$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n\log2^n}{2^{2n}}$$converges. But this series is equal to$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\log2}{2^n}$$which clearly converges.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat after me: $\ln n\to \infty$ more slowly than any positive power of $n.$ In other words,

$$\frac{\ln n}{n^p} \to 0\,\text { for any } p> 0.$$

Once you have absorbed this, you'll know such things as

$$\frac{\ln n}{n^2}< \frac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}  = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

for large $n.$ Which in the case of your series proves convergence by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Apply the integral test, and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to show it directly.  Note that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(n)} = \infty$$
(if you need convinced, just apply L'Hospital's Rule).

Thus $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ such that }\sqrt{n} > \log(n) \quad \forall n > N. \quad$ So we write:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\log(n)}{n^2} + \sum_{n=N + 1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^2} &< C_N + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2} \\
&<  C_N + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} = K \in \mathbb{R^+}\end{align*}
$$
Where $C_N > 0$ is some positive constant since $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log(n)}{n^2}$ is a finite, positive sum and $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges as it is a $p$-series with $p = \frac{3}{2} > 1$.